# XLinux PPP: wvdial exit code 16 no debug details

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ppp, 3g

I'm trying to use a 3G USB modem on a Rapsbian RPi and all goes well, except for some reason the PPP disconnects with exit code 16.
I have debug mode enabled, but it doesn't say nothing, except that authentication is successful.

Please see details below:

```
 WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
 Initializing modem.
 Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
 Sending: AT+CPIN=XXXX
AT+CPIN=XXXX
OK
 Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
 Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"
OK
 Modem initialized.
 Sending: ATD*99#
 Waiting for carrier.
ATD*99#
CONNECT 3600000
 Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
 Starting pppd at Sun Dec  7 22:23:20 2014
 Pid of pppd: 2967
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 Using interface ppp0
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 Authentication (CHAP) started
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 Authentication (CHAP) successful
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 pppd: 8�f[01]P�f[01]h�f[01]��f[01]؉f[01]0�f[01]
 Disconnecting at Sun Dec  7 22:23:24 2014
 The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
 man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
 Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
 Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
```

The /var/log/messages shows:

```
Dec  7 22:58:45 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Dec  7 22:58:45 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: Using interface ppp0
Dec  7 22:58:45 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
Dec  7 22:58:45 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Dec  7 22:58:45 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Dec  7 22:58:48 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: Modem hangup
Dec  7 22:58:48 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: Connection terminated.
Dec  7 22:58:48 raspberrypi pppd[3779]: Exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out.
The issue was that after the SIM card PIN has been entered wvdial proceeds to dialing.
This is too fast. After the PIN is entered the card needs time to register to the network.

I have created to dial scripts, one just enters the PIN CODE, there is a wait of 20sec and then the other dials the 3G network and now it works reliably.

Comment: Could you plese share this script please?